# Angular 6 : Observable<PaginatedResult<User[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'

Tags: angular, pagination, angular6

I am trying to implement pagination in angular 6 after i implemented necessary steps in server, but i am receiving an error.

This is pagination.ts

```
export interface Pagination {
  currentPage: number;
  itemsPerPage: number;
  totalItems: number;
  totalPage: number;
}

export class PaginatedResult<T> {
  result: T;
  pagination: Pagination;
}
```

This method where i am getting the error

```
getUsers(page?: number, itemsPerPage?: number): Observable<User[]> {
    const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<User[]> = new PaginatedResult<User[]>();
    let queryString = '?';

    if (page != null && itemsPerPage != null) {
      queryString += 'pageNumber=' + page + '&pageSize=' + itemsPerPage;
    }

    return this.http
      .get(this.baseUrl + 'users' + queryString, this.jwt())
      .pipe(map((res: Response) =>  {
        paginatedResult.result = res.json();
        if (res.headers.get('Pagination') != null) {
          paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(
            res.headers.get('Pagination')
          );
        }
        return paginatedResult;
      }))
      .pipe(catchError(this.handlerError));
  }
```

This is the error

[image]

This the same method in a tutorial

[image]

Comment: You've defined your function to return `Observable<User[]>`, but your `map` function is mapping it to `PaginatedResult<User[]>` instead

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. The body of the method makes sure you return an observable of PaginatedResult, but the return type of the method is Observable<User[]> . Change the return type.

Comment: the same function worked fine in a tutorial !!

Comment: @JamesFallon That's not possible I'm afraid

Comment: recheck the question

Comment: Either the tutorial is wrong, or you need to go further and see the author fix the error. The TypeScript compiler is more thustworthy than a random tutorial.

Comment: man .. believe me everything worked fin in his tutorial

Comment: Did you use this tutorial? It looks like it based on your code. If you did, you will see that the return type should be as @JBNizet has mentioned, based on the tutorial (see the `getSchedules` method). https://chsakell.com/2016/06/27/angular-2-crud-modals-animations-pagination-datetimepicker/